# Incorrect answer while performing topological sort via DFS in Java

Tags: java

I have been provided a graph in from of an adjacency list along with it's total vertices. I have to perform topological sorting via DFS & print elements in that order.

Total vertices -> 5

The adjacency list ->

0-> 2,3

1-> 3,4

2-> 3

The correct output should be -> 0,1,2,4,3 ( any other order will also work).

My output is -> 1,4,0,2,3.

I tried really hard but could not find the error. Can someone please guide me

```
public static void topologicalSort(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList,int vertices){
        boolean[] visited=new boolean[vertices];
        Stack<Integer> ourStack=new Stack<>();
        for(int i=0;i<vertices;i++){
            if(!visited[i]){
                DFSRecursive(adjList,i,visited,ourStack);
            }
        }
        while(!ourStack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(ourStack.pop() + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void DFSRecursive(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList,int source,boolean[] visited,Stack<Integer> ourStack){
        visited[source]=true;
        for(int element : adjList.get(source)){
            if(!visited[element]){
                DFSRecursive(adjList,element,visited,ourStack);
            }
        }
        ourStack.push(source);
    }
```

Comment: You should notice something is fishy by the fact that you never update `adjList` in `DFSRecursive()`, no...?

Comment: I just confirmed from a friend that 1,4,0,2,3 is also a correct topological sort order. I though all vertices with indegree 0 have to be printed first i.e 0 & 1 have to be printed first but it turns out there is only one condition for topological sorting i.e if there exists 2 vertices such that u->v , then u has to printed before v. It is an observed pattern that the first element printed has indegree 0 always but element after that have to follow the above mentioned singled condition only. So yeah , I got confused. Thanks for helping though !

Comment: @RudraRaina I was scratching my head on this very exact issue today. Thanks to your comment, it makes sense now